# Count number of times the get method in a dict returns the second option

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to build a list from the values of a dictionary, and use the `get` method to handle the missing values:

```
dic = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
list_values = [dic.get(k, 0) for k in ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']]
print(list_values)
>>> [1, 2, 0]
```

The thing is that I want to know how many times the `get` method returned the second option.

I know I could use a simple loop:

```
list_values = []
missing = 0
for k in ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']:
     if k in dic:
         list_values.append(dic[k])
     else:
         missing += 1
         list_values.append(0)
```

But it does not seem really pythonic compared to the list comprehension created beforehand.

Another idea would be to create a function and then use a wrapper to count the number of times the function was called, but *the function is called whether or not the key that is called with `get` exists*, as this simple example shows:

```
dic = {'a': 1}


# Do something to count the number of times the function was called
def missing_value():
    print('eh')
    return 0

print(dic.get('a', missing_value()))
>>> eh
>>> 1
```

Anyone has a simple and elegant solution or should I resolve to use the loop outside of a comprehension dict ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
sum( 1 for k in dic.keys() if k not in ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
```

It avoid to use **get** just to check if the key exist

NB : You can also use the length of sets as follow :

```
L = set(dic.keys())
L2 = set(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
print(len(L2) - len(L & L2))
```

Comment: This is a good idea ! Your answer checks for the number of keys that are in the dictionary but it is not hard to change it for checking those that aren't :)

Comment: Can you provide the example which doesn't work ? dict and the list of item ? Thanks

Comment: use the OPs data, your answer returns `2` when it should return `1`

Comment: You can drop the *list* comprehension within the sum. No need to keep everything in memory -- use a generator.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
cnt = 0
def count_missing():
    global cnt
    cnt += 1
    return 0
d = defaultdict(count_missing)
d['foo'] = 1
d['bar'] = 2
list_values = [d[k] for k in ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']]
print(cnt)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how to use it ? From the documentation and my personal experience with `Collection.defaultdict` it does not seem very helpful...

Answer (score 0):

This will give the desired answer:

```
sum(1 for k in [dic.get(k, 0) for k in ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']] if k == 0)
```

Here is another way:

```
ks = ['foo', 'bar', 'bad']

sum(1 for i in filter(lambda x: type(x) != int, [dic.get(k) for k in ks]))
```

Comment: `dic.get(k)` will return `None` if `k` isn't in `dic` -- no need to provide a default.

Answer (score 0):

The best one i could come up with without ever using `get()`:

```
dic = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
search_keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
missing_keys = [x for x in search_keys if x not in dic.keys()]
print(missing_keys) # prints: ['baz']
print(len(missing_keys)) # prints only the number of missing keys (1)
```

it has the advantage of being readable...